# Find a sequence converging to zero but not the element of $\ell^p$ space for any $1<p<\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I am studying functional analysis and I have a problem about finding a sequence converging to zero such that this sequence is not in $\ell^p$ for any $p$. By $\ell^p$, I mean

$$\ell^p := \left\{ (x_k)=(x_1,x_2,...):\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|^p<\infty \right\}$$ where $1<p<\infty$.

First, I thought of the simple sequence $(1/k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges to zero, but, then, I realized it is an element of $\ell^p$ when $p>2$. I thought of a couple more examples, but they did not work either. Can somebody help me out here?

Comment: my question is . i do not why my question does not seem completely on the above

I am studying functional analysis and I have a problem about finding a sequence converging to zero such that this sequence is not in lp for every p. By lp I mean
lp={(x_k)=(x1,x2,...):Σ|x_k|^p<infinity} where 1<_p<infinity. first I thought very simple sequence 1/k which converges to zero but then I realized when p>_2 it is element of lp space. I thought couple more examples but they did not work either. can somebody help me out here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the sequence $x_k = 1/\ln(k+1)$.

Comment: Wonderfully slow

Comment: @RobertIsrael how do we know that the series $$\sum_{k} \left\vert \frac{1}{\ln (k+1)} \right\vert^p$$ fails to converge for every $p \in [1, +\infty)$?

Comment: @SimonS can you please answer my question in my last comment?

Comment: Limit comparison test with $\sum 1/k$.

Comment: @WesleyStrik Isn't this wrong?

For $k \geq 2$ then we have $|\frac{1}{ln(k+1)}| < 1$. From which we obtain: $|\frac{1}{ln(k+1)}| > |\frac{1}{ln(k+1)}|^p$ for $p \geq 1$

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood If the doubt holds, look at this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957715/how-to-prove-the-divergence-of-sum-frac1-lnk1p-for-p-in-1-inf/3957724?noredirect=1#comment8161702_3957724.

Comment: To prove the convergence for $p\ge 1$, note that $\ln (k+1)\le (k+1)^{\frac 1p}$ for large $k$, whence we get $x_k^p \ge \frac 1{k+1}$ for all large $k$.

Answer (score 9):

If $k \in \mathbb N_{\geq 2}$ $$|\ln(k+1)| > 1$$ 
Now if $p \in \mathbb N_{\geq 1}$  $$|\ln(k+1)|^p \gt |\ln(k+1)| \implies \left| \frac{1}{\ln(k+1)} \right|>\left|\frac{1}{\ln(k+1)}\right|^p$$
By the [Raabe-Duhamel's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#2._Raabe's_test), consider the sequence, $$b_n=n \left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)$$ where $$a_n=\frac{1}{ln(1+n)^p}$$
Then 
$$
\begin{array}\\
L=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n\\
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n\left(\frac{\ln(2+n)^p}{\ln(1+n)^p}-1\right)\\
=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\ln(n+1)}\ln\left(\frac{2+n}{1+n}\right)\sum_{i=0}^{p-1} (-1)^{p-i-1}\left( \frac{\ln(2+n)}{\ln(1+n)} \right)^i\\
=(-1)^{p-1}\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\ln(n+1)}\ln\left(\frac{2+n}{1+n}\right)\\
=(-1)^p \lim\limits_{t \to 0+} \frac{\ln(1+t)}{t\ln(t)} \qquad\text{(Changing Variables } t=\frac{1}{n+1})\\
=(-1)^p \lim\limits_{t \to 0+} \frac{1}{(1+t)(1+\ln(t))}\qquad\text{(By L' Hopital's Rule)}\\ = 0 < 1\\
\end{array}
$$

Hence, the series $\sum_{n\geq1} a_n$ diverges for all $p \geq 1$ i.e. the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{ln(n+1)}\right)_{n\geq1}$ is not $p$-th summable for any $p\geq1$ but converges to $0$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that $\left| \ln(k+1) \right|^p \geq \left| \ln( k + 1) \right|$, since $p \geq 1$ so it can be $p=1$.

Comment: @JezuzStardust if $k=1$, $ln(k+1)=ln(2)<1$ and as a result $|ln(k+1)|^p<|ln(k+1)|$ for every $p>1$. So we must start from $k\geq 2$. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

@Robert Israel's answer is great. And I think the easiest way to prove that the sequence $(x_i), x_i = 1 / \ln (i+1)$ is not in $\ell^p$, where $p$ is a **real number** and $1 \leq  p < \infty$, is using Schlömilch's Generalization of [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

This generalization establishes:

$$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{f(n}) \, \mbox{ converges if and only if }  \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(u(n+1)-u(n)) f(u(n))} \mbox{ converges, }
$$
where $u(n)$ is a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that there is a positive real number $N$, for which:

$$
 \frac{u(n+1)-u(n)}{u(n)-u(n-1)} \, < \, N  \mbox{ para todo } n.
$$

Setting $u(n) = 2^n-1$ and then we have

$$
 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {\frac{1}{\ln (i+1)  ^p}} \, \mbox{ converges if and only if } \, \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{ \frac{2^i}{(\ln (2^i) ) ^p }} = \frac{1}{(\ln (2))^p} \, \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\frac{2^i}{i^p}} \, \mbox { converges }
$$

Since, for all $p$, the term $(\ln(2))^p$ is a constant, we only have to investigate the convergence of the last series.

We will use the ratio test, where, if $L$ is the limit of the ratio of two consecutive terms of the sequence, then, if $L< 1$, the series converges, and, if $L> 1$, the series diverges.

$$
 L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{2^n} \cdot \frac{(n+1)^p}{n^p} = 2 \cdot \lim_{n\to\infty} \left( \frac{n+1}{n} \right)^p = 2
$$

Since $L>1$, the series diverges, as does the original series.